# Dart analyzer is not parsing the dynamic generated files

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I checked and the file is OK.

Dart 1.23.0
AngularDart 3.1.0

The error I am getting is:

Target of URI hasn't been generated: 'file.g.dart'

[image]

Comment: What happens if you restart the analysis server? I have seen this often as well. If you have a good reproduction, please create an issue.

Comment: I am using webstorm, so I don't know how the analysis server is started. I guess it would reiniciate if I kill all dart processes? I did that and didn't help

Comment: Does the file in your question have a `library ...` and the `timeline.g.dart` file a `part of ...` declaration?

Comment: yes and there are more files generated the same way that does not have this error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may help to run "Synchronize" -- bound by default to Ctrl-Q.

You can restart the analyzer on the dart analysis tab, in the top left is a button with arrows running in a circle, if you hover over it it says 'Restart Dart Analysis Server'.

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owXbB.png)

Comment: It should be noted that this answer only applies to Android Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 5):

first check this article :
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json
and make sure of all steps :
1- add dependencies in pubspec.yaml
2- flutter pub get
3- flutter pub upgrade
4- flutter pub run build_runner build

after all, consider that:

```
part 'timeline.g.dart';
```

most be your file name which classes are in!

if your file name is difference with your class name, you should use your file name.

Comment: The question was not related to flutter, and has nothing to do with the current build_runner system, he is running on old version of dart and angular.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. Fixed it following these steps:

```
$ flutter pub get 
$ flutter pub upgrade
$ flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to add this dependency and try it again.

```
dart pub add freezed
dart pub add freezed_annotation 
dart pub add json_serializable --dev
```

Your issue will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

Check have you created a constructor for class with no default parameters. Basically automated file is generated but error happens because it can not find a contractor for model

Answer (score -1):

flutter pub run build_runner build

Just run the above command in the console. Everything will be fine

Comment: Could you just explain your answer?

Comment: The question was not related to flutter, and has nothing to do with the current build_runner system, he is running on old version of dart and angular.